# Meaning of 'use' in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

From MSABC TV show 'community' season 1

> Hi, Senor Chang.
>     What, a community college Spanish teacher can't **use** 80 bucks?

'Use' here seems should mean 'earn', Because the teacher here is a model and He will be paid 80 bucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"can/could(n't) use" is an idiomatic expression effectively meaning "(doesn't) need". You could say, for example:

> I could use some help round here.
>
> I can use a bit of extra cash from time to time now I have the baby.

Answer (score 2):

Here, it is synonymous with **spend**. Its general meaning is that of “make use of” or “employ”.